# How to disable image view's click event?

Tags: android, json, android-imageview

I am getting image array in response,and show it in fullscreen and swipe it,but if my image array is null I need to disable click event and prevent it to go to next activity,I tried lot but do not know what is mistake in my code..follow this for my code..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458980/how-to-send-response-to-next-activity/27498613?noredirect=1#comment43428525_27498613

```
 public class Profile extends Activity{

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(this);

private static final String USER_NAME="name";
private static final String USER_AGE="age";
private static final String USER_LOCATION="location";
private static final String USER_MOTHER_TONGE="mother_tounge";
private static final String USER_OCCU="occupation";
private static final String USER_INCOM="income";
private static final String USER_HEIGHT="height";
private static final String USER_CAST="cast";
private static final String USER_MARRAGE="marital_status";
private static final String USER_RELIGION="religion";
private static final String USER_GOTRA="gotra";
private static final String USER_MANGLIK="manglik";
private static final String USER_RASHI="rashi";
private static final String USER_EDUCATION="education";
private static final String USER_EAT="eating";
private static final String USER_DRINK="drink";
private static final String USER_SMOKE="smoke";
private static final String USER_ABOUT="about_me";
private static final String USER_PIC="profile_pic";
private static final String USER_IMG="user_image";


private static String USER_URL="";  
 private ImageView btnedit;  

private TextView uname;  
private TextView fdetail;  
private TextView sdetail;  
private TextView tdetail;  
private TextView ocdetail;  
private TextView incomedetail;   
private TextView uheight;  
private TextView umrg;  
private TextView ureligion;  
private TextView ugotra;  
private TextView umanglik;  
private TextView urashi;  
private TextView udegree;  
private TextView ueat;  
private TextView udrink;  
private TextView usmoke;  
private TextView uabout;  
private ImageView ucover;  
private TextView occu_second;  
private TextView place_second;  

 String user_name;  
 String user_age;  
 String user_location;  
 String user_mothertong;  
 String user_occupation;  
 String user_income;  
 String user_height;  
 String user_cast;  
 String user_marg;  
 String user_religion;  
 String user_gotra;  
 String user_manglik;  
 String user_rashi;  
 String user_education;  
 String user_eat;  
 String user_drink;  
 String user_smoke;  
 String user_about;  
 String user_pro;  

private TextView age_sceond;

private TextView ucast;

String marital;
 String user_img;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.profile_edit);

String matchId=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

USER_URL=""+matchId;
//Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this,"match id blank",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
 ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

// Making a request to url and getting response
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(USER_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

 try {   
   JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

    user_name = jsonObj.getString(USER_NAME);
    user_age = jsonObj.getString(USER_AGE);
    user_location = jsonObj.getString(USER_LOCATION);
    user_mothertong = jsonObj.getString(USER_MOTHER_TONGE);
    user_occupation = jsonObj.getString(USER_OCCU);
    user_income = jsonObj.getString(USER_INCOM);
    user_height = jsonObj.getString(USER_HEIGHT);
    user_cast=jsonObj.getString(USER_CAST);
    user_marg = jsonObj.getString(USER_MARRAGE);
    user_religion = jsonObj.getString(USER_RELIGION);
    user_gotra = jsonObj.getString(USER_GOTRA);
    user_manglik = jsonObj.getString(USER_MANGLIK);
    user_rashi = jsonObj.getString(USER_RASHI);
    user_education = jsonObj.getString(USER_EDUCATION);
    user_eat = jsonObj.getString(USER_EAT);
    user_drink = jsonObj.getString(USER_DRINK);
    user_smoke = jsonObj.getString(USER_SMOKE);
    user_about = jsonObj.getString(USER_ABOUT);
    user_pro = jsonObj.getString(USER_PIC);
   user_img=jsonObj.getString(USER_IMG);

    user_img = "";

    JSONArray picarray = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("user_image");
    for(int i=0;i< picarray.length();i++)
    {
        user_img+= picarray.getString(i);
      Log.d("mylog", "curent  pro pic  = " + user_img);

    }
    Log.d("mylog", "all images  = " + user_img);


    uname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.namedetail);
    fdetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstdetail);
    sdetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seconddetail);
    tdetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.thirddetail);
    ocdetail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtoccupationdetail);
    incomedetail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.incomedetaile);
    uheight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtheightprofile);
    ucast=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.usercast);
    umrg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmrgprofile);
    ureligion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prohindu);
    ugotra = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gothraa);
    umanglik = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usermanglik);
    urashi = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rashi);
    udegree = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userdegree);
    ueat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txteatprofile);
    udrink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdrinkprofile);
    usmoke = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtsmokeprofile);
    uabout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtabouther);
   ucover = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.coverimage);
   age_sceond=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtageprofile);
   occu_second=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtworkingprofile);
   place_second=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtplaceprofile);

    if(user_name.equals(""))
    {
        uname.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        uname.setText(user_name);
    }
    if(user_age.equals(""))
    {
        fdetail.setText("Not willing to specify");
        age_sceond.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        fdetail.setText(user_age+" years");
        age_sceond.setText(user_age+" years");
    }
    if(user_location.equals(""))
    {
        sdetail.setText("Not willing to specify");
        place_second.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        sdetail.setText(user_location);
        place_second.setText(user_location);
    }
    if(user_mothertong.equals(""))
    {
        tdetail.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        tdetail.setText(user_mothertong);
    }
    if(user_occupation.equals(""))
    {
        ocdetail.setText("Not willing to specify");
        occu_second.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        ocdetail.setText(user_occupation);
        occu_second.setText(user_occupation);
    }
    if(user_income.equals(""))
    {
        incomedetail.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        incomedetail.setText(user_income);
    }
    if(user_height.equals(""))
    {
        uheight.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        uheight.setText(user_height);
    }
    if(user_cast.equals(""))
    {
        ucast.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        ucast.setText(user_cast);
    }
    if(user_marg.equals(""))
    {
        umrg.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        umrg.setText(user_marg);
    }
    if(user_religion.equals(""))
    {
        ureligion.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        ureligion.setText(user_religion);
    }
    if(user_gotra.equals(""))
    {
        ugotra.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        ugotra.setText(user_gotra);
    }
    if(user_manglik.equals(""))
    {
        umanglik.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        umanglik.setText(user_manglik);
    }
    if(user_rashi.equals(""))
    {
        urashi.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        urashi.setText(user_rashi);
    }
    if(user_education.equals(""))
    {
        udegree.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        udegree.setText(user_education);
    }
    if(user_eat.equals(""))
    {
        ueat.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        ueat.setText(user_eat);
        udrink.setText(user_drink);
        usmoke.setText(user_smoke);
    }

    if(user_about.equals(""))
    {
        uabout.setText("Not willing to specify");
    }
    else
    {
        uabout.setText(user_about);
    }
    androidAQuery.id(ucover).image(user_pro, true, true);




 } catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
  ucover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Fullimage.class);
      i.putExtra("images", USER_IMG);
       startActivity(i);

}
 });

btnedit=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.editprofilebutton);
btnedit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 


    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileEdit.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.title_alertbox)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
               .setMessage(R.string.chek)
               .setCancelable(true)
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.okalert, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                   }
               });

        AlertDialog welcomeAlert = builder.create();
        welcomeAlert.show();
        // Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()
        ((TextView)welcomeAlert.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        /*// Creating alert Dialog with one Button

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                ProfileEdit.this).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Edit Profile");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please log on to gujjumatch.com desktop site to edit your profile " +
                "and also set other details or call on 91 281 3054120");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                        // closed
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Thank You", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();*/

    }
});
}
```

fullimageview

```
public class FuLLimage extends Activity{

private String strtd;  
String[] imgStr;  

@Override  
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.full_image_view);

strtd=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("images");
System.out.println("imagess..........." + strtd);

imgStr = strtd.split(",");
System.out.println("Image String Array : " + imgStr);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
   ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
 }  

 public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
 Context context;

  ImageAdapter(Context context)
 {
 this.context=context;
 }
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
 return imgStr.length;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
 return view == ((ImageView) object);
 }

 @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
 int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
 imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgStr[position]));

 //imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imgStr[position]));
 ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
 return imageView;
 }

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
 ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: all of those which is your code can you post your code here

Comment: its not allowing here thats why i mentioned

Comment: which code you are using i am unable to understand sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the lenght of your arraylist and then according the that set a message to user

```
if(picarray.length()!=0)
     {
      ucover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Fullimage.class);
  i.putExtra("images", USER_IMG);
   startActivity(i);

 }
});
}
   else
  {//show your message here
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set listener to null to disable the onclick event

```
ucover.setOnClickListener(null)
```

If you want to resume the click event simply call

```
ucover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Fullimage.class);
          i.putExtra("images", USER_IMG);
           startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Hops this help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your array length and if it is non zero enable the onclick listner..

```
if(picarray.length != 0)
{

ucover.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Fullimage.class);
      i.putExtra("images", USER_IMG);
       startActivity(i);
}
 });

}
```

Comment: where did you disable click event if array is empty or null

Comment: "ucover" is your imageView right?  If yes you can set it only if the array length is non zero.. And if you want to unregister the imageView after the setOnClickListener use  ucover.setOnClickListener(null)